# Failed to index file: Unsupported file type: application/csv when adding csv to retrieval agent

Tags: openai-api

I'm trying to create a retrieval agent with a csv file. I'm able to add this file to the gpt builder, but when working witht he agent beta API I'm getting an error.

```
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
) 
file = client.files.create(file=open("knowledge.csv", "rb"),
                               purpose='assistants')

assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(instructions=<instructions>,,
                                              model="gpt-4-1106-preview",
                                              tools=[{
                                                  "type": "retrieval"
                                              }],
                                              file_ids=[file.id])
```

Error:

```
File "/home/tromanow/anaconda3/envs/agents/lib/python3.11/site-
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Failed to index file: Unsupported file file-KmwSJUOYZFRMGMC9NEUHGY0k type: application/csv', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the .csv format is only supported for the "code_interpreter" type, not "retrieval".
https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/supported-files